# Decoding URI query string in Java

Tags: java, decoding, query-string

I need to decode a URI that contains a query string; expected input/output behavior is something like the following:

```
abstract class URIParser
{       
    /** example input: 
      * something?alias=pos&FirstName=Foo+A%26B%3DC&LastName=Bar */
    URIParser(String input) { ... }
    /** should return "something" for the example input */
    public String getPath(); 
    /** should return a map 
      * {alias: "pos", FirstName: "Foo+A&B=C", LastName: "Bar"} */
    public Map<String,String> getQuery();
}
```

I've tried using [java.net.URI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), but it seems to decode the query string so in the above example I'm left with "alias=pos&FirstName=Foo+A&B=C&LastName=Bar" so there is ambiguity whether a "&" is a query separator or is a character in a query component.

**Edit:** I just tried [URI.getRawQuery()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getRawQuery%28%29) and it doesn't do the encoding, so I can split the query string with a `&`, but then what do I do? Javascript has [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURIComponent), I can't seem to find the corresponding method in Java.

Any suggestions? I would prefer not to use any new libraries.

Comment: Since you don't want to introduce new libs, may I ask in which environment you receive these URIs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See class [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#URLDecoder%28%29)

Comment: It should be noted that you should identify the query part and split the parameters into key/value pairs prior to using this, but it'll decode percent-encoded values to the given encoding (see UTF-8) according to the HTML `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` spec.

Comment: Always put the answer in your answer. Linking out creates extra work and there's no guarantee the link will always work.

Answer (score 70):

Use

```
URLDecoder.decode(proxyRequestParam.replace("+", "%2B"), "UTF-8")
          .replace("%2B", "+")
```

to simulate `decodeURIComponent`. Java's `URLDecoder` decodes the plus sign to a space, which is not what you want, therefore you need the replace statements.

> **Warning:** the `.replace("%2B", "+")` at the end *will* corrupt your data *if* the original (pre-x-www-form-urlencoded) contained that string, as @xehpuk pointed out.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. URIs treat the + symbol as it is, whereas spaces are encoded into %20. URLDecoder is not compatible with URI encoded strings as it will decode both + and %20 into a space.

Comment: What's the point of the second replace? After the decode there will no longer be any instances of "%2B" in the string since they will have all been replaced with "+", so there will be nothing for the replace to match.

Comment: The point is that you don't want encoded characters in a decoded string. Since Java does not decode the +-sign as JavaScript does I first encode the +-sign so that it won't be touched by Java and then decode the %2B into +-sign.

To be short: if I wouldn't do this the decoded URL would not contain the original +-signs (since Java would have lost them in the decoding phase).

Comment: @janb - I think the second replace is unnecessary, because the `decode` method will already convert any `%2B` it finds into `+`.  The first replace is necessary to stop it converting `+` into spaces.

Comment: @StevePowell The second replace is not only unnecessary, it's wrong.

Comment: @xehpuk, @StevePowell: in some situations (as the one I have desribed above) it is needed, because you don't want to lose any '+' character if it is intentionally in the incomming parameter. By using the second replace, you mimic the behavior of JavaScript's `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: For example, string `"%252B"` would be decoded by your solution incorrectly as `"+"`, while `decodeURIComponent("%252B") === "%@B"`. Is there any example to demonstrate the necessity of last replace?

Answer (score 7):

```
var reqParam =  URLDecoder.decode(reqParam, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: java7+ `URLDecoder.decode(objectKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: Will it work for string containing + operator?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with the + sign :

I made a helper class that wraps the URLDecoder function based on the answer of @janb

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateDecoder {

    private static final String KEY_DATE = "datekey";

    private static final SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT =
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ", Locale.US);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://asdf.com?something=12345&" +
                    KEY_DATE +"=2016-12-24T12:00:00+01:00");

            System.out.println("parsed date: " + DateDecoder.createDate(uri)); // parsed date: Sat Dec 24 12:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public static Date createDate(@Nullable Uri data) {
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                String withPlus = decodeButKeepPlus(KEY_DATE, data.getEncodedQuery());
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(withPlus)) {
                    return SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.parse(withPlus);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * copied from android.net.Uri.java
     */
    @Nullable
    public static String decodeButKeepPlus(String encodedKey, String completeEncodedQuery)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        final int length = completeEncodedQuery.length();
        int start = 0;
        do {
            int nextAmpersand = completeEncodedQuery.indexOf('&', start);
            int end = nextAmpersand != -1 ? nextAmpersand : length;

            int separator = completeEncodedQuery.indexOf('=', start);
            if (separator > end || separator == -1) {
                separator = end;
            }

            if (separator - start == encodedKey.length()
                    && completeEncodedQuery.regionMatches(start, encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length())) {
                if (separator == end) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    String encodedValue = completeEncodedQuery.substring(separator + 1, end);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(encodedValue)) {
                        return URLDecoder.decode(encodedValue.replace("+", "%2B"), "UTF-8").replace("%2B", "+");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Move start to end of name.
            if (nextAmpersand != -1) {
                start = nextAmpersand + 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new java.net.URI(proxyRequestParam).getPath()
```

The string encoded by js encodeURIComponent should just be a path, without schema and other things. However it still a valid input for java.net.URI. So java.net.URI will do everything for us and then the path of it is what we want.