# How to pass html entity on jquery ajax to java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

Basically I have a form with a textbox.

Some of the input value contains html entities (specifically <, >).

Say I input "<" and pass my values as such:

`var theDescription = $("#inMaintDescription").val()`

```
$.ajax( {
        url : "Ajax.faces",
        type : "GET",
        cache : false,
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data : {
            description: theDescription
```

However when it reaches java, it becomes

```
String theDescription = inRequest.getParameter(RequestConstants.AJAX_REQUEST_VARIABLE_DESCRIPTION);
```

theDescription is literally `&lt;` instead of `<`

How can I input < on my text box and the java string receives it as < ? Is string replacement on java the only way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: decoding URI query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632175/java-decoding-uri-query-string)

Comment: Have you tried data type text/HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()

Comment: Edit: I made this to work by using unEscapeHtml on the last method that uses my value with html entities. Thanks!