# Spring REST: DTO as parameter - values are not urldecoded

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST controller with a RequestMapping that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyDTO> search(SearchParameters searchParameters) {
        // ...
}
```

and call it like that: `/data/search?name=some%20value&....`

`searchParameters` **is** populated, but the values are not being urldecoded. So instead of setting `searchParameter`'s attribute `name` to "some value" it is "some%20value". How can I instruct Spring to urldecode these values?

Comment: why not use a `@RequestParam("yourparametername")String yourparameter` for each request parameter instead of a DTO, this is proven to be working.

Comment: There are about 15 search parameters, it's tedious to write out and hard to read afterwards.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632175/decoding-uri-query-string-in-java, or check out my answer below for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a Map and have their names stored statically in a class, like :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyDTO> search(@RequestParam Map<String,String> parameters) {
        String name = parameters.get(SearchParameters.NAME);
// ...
}
```

or use the Map to build the Object SearchParameters:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<MyDTO> search(@RequestParam Map<String,String> parameters) {
            SeachParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters(parameters);
    // ...
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't change things for me. The map looks exactly like the DTO, i.e. it doesn't properly decode things.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was not actually the decoding, but the encoding. It was encoded in a test case, although it wouldn't have needed to be. So the URL looking like `/data/search?name=some%20value` should really have been `/data/search?name=some value` with actual spaces.